# How to mock termination of proces which start was mocked too

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest

I don't know maybe it's common problem but i can't handle with it and can't find the answear.

I have class with is used to open and terminate some proecess:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class foo(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.process = None
    self.command = 'some command'

def _start_process(self, duration):
    self.process = Popen([self.command, '-d'], stdout=PIPE)

def _terminate_process(self):
    self.process.terminate()
    <other_instructions>
```

And now I have mock both `_start_process` and `_terminate_process`, i handled with `_start_process`:

```
import pytest
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
from mock import MagicMock, patch
monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()
import file.foo

def bar():
    test_object = file.foo()
    monkeypatch.setattr('subprocess.Popen', MagicMock())
    test_object._start_process()
```

And it works. But I'm not able to mock `_terminate_process`. Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the code where you attempt to mock _terminate_process.

Comment: Thats the point, I don't know how to do it. I tried `monkeypatch.setattr('subprocess.terminate', MagicMock())` and `monkeypatch.setattr('terminate', MagicMock())` and others variations but `E           AttributeError: 'module' object at subprocess has no attribute 'terminate'
` or `E           TypeError: must be absolute import path string, not 'terminate'` e.t.c

Comment: I didn't mentionet it before but i can't mock whole `_terminate_process` because this functions make some `<other_instructions>` and I need to mock only terminating process

Comment: [`terminate` is an instance method of `Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate), so `subprocess.terminate` is meaningless. However, according to your code, you’re mocking `Popen` itself, so `_start_process` shouldn’t be creating a process at all, meaning the first line of `_terminate_process` will be a no-op, and it should happily continue past that as-is. Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Yup, without anything I receive:
`>       self.process.terminate()
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'

Comment: What is the value of `self.process` after the `Popen` call in `_start_process` and then at the start of `_terminate_process`?

Comment: What can it be? It's an Popen class object.